# Can fusion see through newtype wrappers?

Tags: haskell, optimization, fusion

Given:

```
newtype MyVec = MyVec { unVec :: Data.Vector } 
  deriving (Functor, etc)
```

This will create (something like) this:

```
instance Functor MyVec where
  fmap f = MyVec . Data.Vector.fmap f . unVec
```

Will Vectors fusion rules fire and rewrite `fmap f . fmap g $ myVec` into `fmap (f . g) myVec`?

Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of? Afaik the problem where you "pay" for new types in containers was solved in GHC 7.8, was it?

Answer (score 17):

Fusion rules operate on functions, not on types. Your functions on MyVec won't have fusion rules, unless you write them to reuse the underlying ones.

E.g.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> MyVec a -> MyVec b
map f = MyVec . Vector.map f . unVec
{-# INLINE map #-}
```

Then we'd have uses:

```
map f . map g
```

which will inline to:

```
MyVec . Vector.map f . unVec . MyVec . Vector.map g . unVec
```

GHC should then erase the newtype constructor, yielding a regular stream, suitable for fusion:

```
MyVec . Vector.map f . Vector.map g . unVec
```

You can confirm this by running GHC and looking at the rewrite rules firing. 
Alternatively, you can add your own "MyVec.  unVec" rewrite rule, but GHC should already cover that.

Comment: [The Haskell wiki](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Data_types#Newtypes) states that "`newtype`s cost nothing". Shouldn't it be reworded if it is indeed the case that they prevent some optimizations?

Comment: Shouldn't the definition of `map` have a call to `MyVec` in it, e.g. 'map f x = MyVec $ Vector.map f (unVec x)`?

Comment: First question: how do I find out about the relevant rewrite rules. When I use `-ddump-rule-firings` I see thousand firings... Which if them are relevant?

Comment: Second question: will generic new type derived code be automatically  inlined? Else, how do I attach `INLINE` (or better `INLINABLE`?) pragmas to derived type classes?